# Is there a way to download files from a large list of addresses each linking to a single file?

Tags: download, bulk

My organization is getting a new hosted site and I need to download a large number of files from our current site. These files are being hosted elsewhere. The way our existing site handles the files is unfortunately a black box to me and I have to work around it to get what I need. I got a long list of links for the files I need, but they are links, not filenames that I could just drop in to a browser and save. For example, here is a one of the entries.

> Agenda and Link to the 9/19/23 Audit Committee Meeting Sep 19, 2023
> .../AgendaCenter/ViewFile/Agenda/_09192023-804

When you go to the link, it brings up a PDF file with a unique name that doesn't match the link. In this case, the filename is `09-19-2023 Audit Committee Agenda.pdf`.

Ideally, what I'd like to do is to have an app or script that I could feed in this list of entries and it would download all the files it finds when visiting the links and then have the option of appending the filename with a unique identifier so we can tell which file goes with which entry. There are over 700 entries, so it's hard to match them based on the names, and very easy to mix them up. But, even if there is no option to rename the files, just being able to do this with a bulk process would be a vast improvement.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you accessing these? It's been a very long time since I admined a web site, but we always used an FTP app, so you can see the real structural hierarchy, rather than just that presented to the web interface.

Comment: Powershell can download files, and should have no trouble stepping through a list of links. Another way is using browser plugins: In the past I've saved documents full of links as html pages and opened them in Firefox running the DownThemAll plugin and then used that plugin to download all the links.

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: Tetsujin - Unfortunately, the files are being hosted by CivicPlus, and we no access beyond direct download or the admin interface, which is actually slower. I reached out to them and they aren't willing to do what I requested without having us pay one of their developers to custom engineer a solution.

Comment: music2myear - I've looked at DownThemAll and I don't know if it will work. The pages being accessed don't have any code, per se. So there are no 'links' on the page. There is just some kind of redirection voodoo happening in the background and the PDF file is presented on screen. I will give it a shot and report back here with the result.

Comment: We're working with Windows. In theory, the activity could take place anywhere since we're getting the files from a browser.

Comment: K J - Thanks for that, we do have an Excel file with everything in it, I figured I'd have to have a rename column that I build myself, which wouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having FTP access to the site is best because that would allow you to download the folder AND file structure simultaneously.

If you don't want to go through that, or you won't be granted FTP access, those who DO have FTP access will be better suited to accomplish this, but... if that is absolutely not an option:

Use the [DownThemAll](https://www.downthemall.org/) utility. I've used it extensively in Firefox, but apparently they publish their plugins for Opera, Edge, and Chrome as well.

1. Save the document with the list of links as an HTML file, making sure each of those links are actual hyperlinks (that you can click to go directly to downloading the file).
2. Open this HTML file inside the browser you've installed the DownThemAll plugin in.
3. (optional) if you wish, open the DownThemAll plugin settings and configure a default save location. It may also prompt you to do this on first use if you don't configure it now.
4. Right-click on the page and use the appropriate DownThemAll plugin command to download all of the links on the page. If you didn't complete step 3 previously you'll be prompted to choose a save location. Make sure to choose the option to save all downloads to that location so you don't have to deal with that prompt for each individual file.
5. Profit...

Comment: You were absolutely right - even though the links led directly to the files, DownThemAll knew exactly what to do and got the files. Thanks very much!